# Choosing Geographic Transformation from D_WGS_1984 to D_Hughes_1980 in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I am using ArcMap 10.2 and I want to convert the shapefile projection(from **GCS_WGS_1984** to **NSIDC_Sea_Ice_Polar_Stereographic_North**), however, their datum is different,the datum of GCS_WGS_1984 is **D_WGS_1984** and **NSIDC_Sea_Ice_Polar_Stereographic_North** is **D_Hughes_1980**. Therefore, Geographic Transformation is must be filled（as is shown in Fig.1), however, I cannot find **D_WGS_1984_To_D_Hughes_1980** in drop-down list of valid transformation methods, as Fig.2.

I want to know the content to fill in ***Geographic Transformation*** field.

[image]
                     Fig.1
[image]
                     Fig.2

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the version of ArcGIS in use.

Answer (score 1):

[This document](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003r/pdf/geographic_transformations.pdf) details the various transformations available in ArcGIS.  You will need to to review the information on your options to determine which transformation is best suited for your area of interest.  Keep in mind that some transformation are better for wide areas and some are better suited to specific states or regions.  Sometimes it is necessary to use two transformations to get the job done.